# Continuing a clock from a string representation of a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following string representing a time:

```
var s = "22:01:15";
```

I want to increment that time along with the system clock, but add to my existing value.

How do I continue this as if it was a real clock no matter what the actual computer clock time is?

Comment: Edited to be more understandable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take that time, parse it into a `Date` instance, and determine the difference between that and the system's date. Then apply that offset.

1. Parse it:

   ```
   var parts = str.split(":");
   ```
2. Apply that to a date

   ```
   var dt = new Date();
   dt.setHours(parseInt(parts[0], 10));
   dt.setMinutes(parseInt(parts[1], 10));
   dt.setSeconds(parseInt(parts[2], 10));
   ```
3. Get the difference

   ```
   var diff = new Date().getTime() - dt.getTime();
   ```
4. Apply it any time you're going to display the value

   ```
   var now = new Date(new Date().getTime() - diff);
   ```
5. Use the `now` instance to display

You do steps 1 - 4 once, at the outset; then repeat step 5 as necessary.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/akana4/2)

Comment: Write in a function and us the following code setTimeout(function(){timeCount()}, 1000);

Comment: @iUngi To update `now` automatically from a timeout function would require at least 2x frequency of the desired observation -- or 500ms (this can be avoided with careful scheduling). I would just call the function to compute `now` as needed (keeping the above statement in mind).

Comment: @iUngi: Exactly, but that can be simply `setTimeout(timeCount, 1000);` For this sort of thing I see a lot of granularity issues, so I'd tend toward a lower number. But that's the idea.

Comment: +1 For actual code, using a Date as the internal structure, and inverting the delta calculation.

Comment: Calculating the delta from the clock start time and the current time at clock start (done once), not from the time when the clock is *started* and the current time (done each time the clock time is read). Sometimes the smallest things escape me...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like a [countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and do a count up.

```
$('#sinceCountdown').countdown({since: CUSTOMTIMEVAR, 
    format: 'HMS', description: 'Custom Time'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script will do it for you:

In short, it takes the difference between some date during that time and compare it with current date, and then use that difference on an interval to update the current time.

```
var t = $('#time').text().split(":");

var d = new Date(2011, 01, 01 , t[0], t[1], t[2],0);
var d1 = new Date();

var diff = d.getTime()-d1.getTime();


window.setInterval(function(){

 d1 = new Date();
 d1.setTime(d1.getTime()+diff);
    $('#time').text(ze(d1.getHours())+":"+ze(d1.getMinutes())+":"+ze(d1.getSeconds()));
},1000);


function ze(num) {   
    if (num.toString().length<=1){
     return "0"+num;   
    }else{
     return num;   
    }   
}
```

**working example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/xsVD4/**